# If Microsoft wants me to change my Microsoft Account password, is there anything I can do to avoid it?

Tags: microsoft-account

I have begun being notified within Windows and in the Microsoft website that

> It looks like someone else might be using your account

I went to check my recent sign in activity, following the link [from this help page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/4306f1e9-c0b7-40da-b272-f443bb6fabf9/check-the-recent-sign-in-activity-for-your-microsoft-account), but it won't show me anything without me first changing my password.

This seems like a terrible set up - if they think my account is compromised, shouldn't I at least be able to see why? I can understand making it very difficult to say "no, that activity is me" (because if it was easy then hackers would just do that) but I can't see the harm in letting me *see* the activity.

What's going on here? What would be causing this status to my account? Is there any way to get around it and see the sign in activity? Will I eventually just need to change my password even if there was no suspicious activity?

Comment: Why can't you just change your password?

Comment: @JasonC I shouldn't be forced to change it without being told why!

Comment: But you are. So... you know. They did tell you it was because it looked like your account was compromised. That's just how they chose to implement that security policy.

Comment: So change your password and then change it back.

Comment: @Ramhound Can you confirm that will work? Many companies will not let you reuse old passwords, especially if they think they were compromised.

Comment: @curiousdannii MS might not and I don't know, but as an aside, some unsolicited advice: We live in an age where cyber security is extremely important yet not taken seriously by many consumers (and companies alike). If you are resistant to changing your password because it's highly inconvenient for you, you *could* look at this as a possible red flag that your general personal password choosing / management strategy isn't as great is it could be. Now may be a good time to come up with ways to make changing passwords more convenient, changing them is something you should be doing anyways. [1/2]

Comment: @curiousdannii Sort of like how people balk when e.g. their debit card number has to change because "dang, now I have to remember all these sites I've got auto payments set up on, remember my electric company password, etc. and change them all", but if you keep an offline list of where you've used your card, it's a lot easier to change it, and then you are better able to respond to security threats, etc. *when* they come up. [2/2]

Comment: @Jason I'm not opposed to changing passwords, especially for something as unimportant as a Microsoft account ;). I am very annoyed at its refusal to give any information. If it will let me log in to Windows and the Microsoft site with my current password, then surely it's safe enough to let me see the sign in history. I also have nothing that gives me any confidence they won't ask me to change it again soon after for secret reasons once more. (Again if they had a policy of requiring regular changes that would be okay. It's really the complete lack of transparency that's the problem.)

Comment: @curiousdannii Do you recall / can you find out / [does anybody with an MS account know] *exactly* what info is displayed on the sign-in history? If so I think we can reformulate your question as a concrete security question regarding the risks associated with the info on that page. Right now it's on its way to a POB closure since "why did MS do this" in its current form, at least given my own knowledge of it, it is arguably a design choice that only the responsible MS dev could answer. So ultimately this Q will probably need a salvage edit anyways.

Comment: @Jason I've never looked at it before. All I can assume is that it would be similar to Google's.

Comment: @curiousdannii I just remembered I have an old live.com account. So first interesting thing is, even when logged in, when I go to the sign-in activity page they *still* make me enter a two-step verification code sent to my alternate email address. The page is prefaced with "to access sensitive information..." (note: there *is* a checkbox to disable this for future requests). So clearly they at least feel this info is more sensitive than most other account info, and I *do* trust their security analysts more than I trust our random opinions on the matter. So let's see what's on the page...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53033/discussion-between-curiousdannii-and-jason-c).

Answer (score 1):

The reason they do this is simply because they feel the information on that page is too sensitive to continue revealing to a potential attacker, and they assume there is a potential attacker because for whatever reason their system flagged the account as potentially compromised.

Here is a screen shot of that page (I've left the maps uncensored as it's no secret that I'm in NYC, it's on my profile):

[image]

This contains a few obvious bits of sensitive information:

- Your IP address history, which not only is a potential direct risk (e.g. if an attacker is trying to target *you*, they now know e.g. which machines to potentially, say, scan for vulnerabilities on, and they also know the OS being used to help them out), but also can give up your location with sometimes eerie accuracy ([stackoverflow.com](https://tools.keycdn.com/geo?host=151.101.129.69), and when I type in mine it's within about 200 feet of my house).
- Other approximate location information.
- Device history and usage patterns, which, depending on your patterns, an attacker might be able to glean some information out of. E.g. I can start to build a vague picture of your personal real life patterns by piecing together access times and locations.
- Whatever other things may appear on this page besides the "successful sign-in" and "successful password reset" log entries, I do not know.

These are all things I wouldn't want a truly malicious person to know. Even if I don't quite understand the direct risks or how they'd use this information, I trust that Microsoft's professional security analysts have more of a handle on cyber / real-life attack vectors than I do. If you'd like to know more about specific attack possibilities, the folks on https://security.stackexchange.com/ may be able to help with a more concrete question about it.

Even if you don't see it as a security issue at the bare minimum it's a *privacy* issue.

So, agree or not, Microsoft feels this info is too sensitive to continue releasing freely on a potentially compromised account.

It's worth noting that when I request the recent activity page, even if I am already logged in, I am still prompted with a two-step verification code sent to my alternate email address (although there is a checkbox to disable this labelled "I use this device frequently, do not prompt for a code in the future"), on a page prefaced with "to access sensitive information...". So this also drives home the importance MS places on this data.